# I cannot access the movies list I created (python)

Tags: python, list, indexing, menu

I am currently having issues having my program access my list after the user enters a menu option. the only entry being read is the 1939 entry, any other year will only present the "enter a valid year" option. Another issue is when displaying categories, only the first 2 drama films will pop up, every other category doesn't work when asked for. It also will not display the entire list when I call to display it (only the 1939 entry would pop up). Any help would be very appreciated!

```
movies = [[1939,'Gone With the Wind','drama'],
[1943,'Casablanca','drama'],
[1965,'The Sound of Music','musical'],
[1969,'Midnight Cowboy','drama'],
[1972,'The Godfather','drama'],
[1973,'The String','comedy'],
[1977,'Annie Hall','comedy'],
[1981,'Chariots of Fire','drama'],
[1984,'Amadeus','historical'],
[1986,'Platoon','action'],
[1988,'Rain Man','drama'],
[1990,'Dances with Wolves','western'],
[1992,'Unforgiven','western'],
[1993,'Schindlers List','historical'],
[1994,'Forrest Gump','comedy'],
[1995,'Braveheart','historical'],
[1997,'Titanic','historical'],
[1998,'Shakespeare in Love','comedy'],
[2001,'A Beautiful Mind','historical'],
[2002,'Chicago','musical'],
[2009,'The Hurt Locker','action'],
[2010,'The Kings Speech','historical'],
[2011,'The Artist','comedy'],
[2012,'Argo','historical'],
[2013,'12 Years a Slave','drama'],
[2014,'Birdman','comedy'],
[2016,'Moonlight','drama'],
[2017,'The Shape of Water','fantasy'],
[2018,'Parasite','comedy']]

menu = """
    1 - Display winning movie for a selected year
    2 - Display movie and category for a selected year
    d - Display entire movie list
    dc - Display movies in a selected category - year and title
    q = quit
"""

while True:
    print(menu)
    option = input("Please enter a valid menu option from above: ")
    if option in 'qQ':
        print("Ending program")
        break
    elif option == "1":
        year = int(input("Please enter a valid year: "))
        for m in movies:
            if year == m[1]:
                print("The winning movie in ", year," was: ", m[1])
            else:
                print("Input a valid year")
                break
    elif option == "2":
        year = int(input("Please enter a valid year: "))
        for m in movies:
            if year == m[0]:
                print("The winning movie was: ", m[1], "and its category was: ", m[2])
            else:
                print("Please enter a valid year")
                break
    elif option == "d":
        for m in movies:
            print(m[0], m[1], m[2])
            break
    elif option == "dc":
        cat = input("Please enter a valid category")
        for m in movies:
            if cat == m[2]:
                print(m[0], m[1])
            else:
                print("Please enter a valid category")
                break
    else:
        print()
        print("Please select a valid option")
```

Comment: List indexes start at 0, not 1. So it should be `m[0]` through `m[2]`

Answer (score 0):

At m[1] pulls movie name and not year.

Converting year input to integer and comparing.

```
if int(year) == m[0]:
```

Also, Breaks are used improperly. for display option index are not correctly used.

```
 print(m[0], m[1], m[2])
```

Corrected Code

---

```
while True:
    print(menu)
    option = input("Please enter a valid menu option from above: ")
    if option in 'qQ':
        print("Ending program")
        break
    elif option == "1":
        year = input("Please enter a valid year: ")
        print(year)
        for m in movies:
            if int(year) == m[0]:
                print("The winning movie in ", year," was: ", m[1])
    elif option == "2":
        year = input("Please enter a valid year: ")
        for m in movies:
            if int(year) == m[0]:
                print("The winning movie was: ", m[1], "and its category was: ", m[2])

    elif option == "d":
        for m in movies:
            print(m[0], m[1], m[2])

    elif option == "dc":
        cat = input("Please enter a valid category : ")
        for m in movies:
            if cat == m[2]:
                print(m[1], m[2])
    else:

        print("Please select a valid option")
```

Comment: ohhhh okay i see so my formatting and the unnecessary breaks must've stopped the reading on the list at the first entry. thank you so much!!